# How can I center two iframes side by side until they are of a minimum width, then set their width to 100%?

Tags: css, iframe

I am trying to center two iframe elements side by side, where they both take up half (47.5%) of the page, until they are of a minimum width of something like 500px.  I have achieved this, but I want to make it so that when one of these iframes reaches 500px, it will change its width to 100%, so that they will then be centered on top of one another when they get too small to be side by side.  The goal for this is to have two forms on one page.

I have tried using a media query to fix this issue, but from what I can find online and can test myself, media queries can't test the width of an iframe element, but rather the screen itself.

I have used this CSS code to attempt this:

```css
iframe {
  width: 47.5%;
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;

  float: left;
}

@media iframe and (max-width: 500px) {
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I expected this to accurately resize the iframes to 100%, but unfortunately it did not, and they just remained the same size.

Hopefully you can help me out here, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove max-width or define it again on the media query as `100%`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing `min-width` on the iframe and adding `max-width` to the media query, and then styled the iframes' `width` to `100%`.

```css
iframe {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin: 0;

  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: calc(500px*3.1)) {
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```